# Show that $\lim_{x \to x_0}x^2 = x_0^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Define a function $f(x):=x^2$ Show that the limit of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is $x_0^2$.

So I have proved that given any $\delta>0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have $|x+x_0|<2|x_0|+\delta$.

By using this fact, if we let $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta=$something, then $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-x_0^2|=|x^2-x_0^2|=|x+x_0||x-x_0|<(2|x_0|+\delta)\delta$.

How can I set my $\delta$ so that the inequality works?

Comment: Start with "deciding" that $\delta\leq1$ so that $|x^2-x_0^2|<(2|x_0|+1)\delta$. Then (with that in the back of your head) choose $\delta=\min(1,r)$ where $r>0$ and $(2|x_0|+1)r<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

We want:
$$f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)<\epsilon$$
for $f(x):=x^2$, so
$$\delta^2 + 2x_0\delta <\epsilon$$
Solving this inequality gives us the following interval:
$$\delta \in (-\sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-x_0, \sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-x_0)$$
Of course we want only positive $\delta$, so 
$$\delta \in (0, \sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-x_0)$$
For negative $x_0$ our interval gets very wide, so let's make it a little shorter (and independent on the sign of $x_0$):
$$\delta \in (0, \sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-|x_0|)$$
Now you can take $\delta = \frac{\sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-|x_0|}{2}$ and your inequality will be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $|x_0^2-x^2|=|x_0-x||x_0+x|$

Take $\delta<1$

We have that $|x_0+x| \leq|x_0|+|x| \leq |x_0|+(|x_0-x|+|x_0|)\leq |x_0|+\delta+|x_0|<2|x_0|+1$

Thus $|x_0^2-x^2| <\delta(2|x_0|+1)$

Take $\delta< \min\{\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0|+1},1\}$ and you are done.

This $\delta>0$ makes the inequality work.

You can check this as an exercise.